# to send video stream to Browser by using Gstreamer

Tags: html, gstreamer, rtsp, gst-launch-1.0

I am trying to send video data from my Ubuntu server to Browser using HTML5 and Gstreamer.
On Ubuntu I am running

> gst-launch -v videotestsrc ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink
>   host=192.168.XX.XX port=8080

and my HTML Tag is as below:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>gst-stream</title>
</head>

<body>
  <video width=320 height=240 autoplay>
      <source src="192.168.xx.xx:8080">
   </video>
</body>

</html>
```

But i am not able to receive any stream.What i need to do to receive the stream in browser

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify protocol in url

Also you can check http://192.168.xx.xx:8080 directly in browser

Comment: But gstreamer is not speaking HTTP in this case, does it?